# How to pass parameters to makebst?

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

Is it any way to pass parameters to makebst, like seq-no, instead of interactively answer the questions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I've never used makebst but I suspect that you can do what you want by hacking the standard "MASTER file", merlin.mbs.